# Implementing generator throw() method in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, generator, pybind11

I'm implementing a generator in C++ using pybind11 and the bit I'm having difficulty with is implementing the `throw` method.

In python it has this signature and typical implementation:

```py
def throw(self, exception_type: type | None = None, exception_message: str | None = None, traceback: Any | None = None) -> None:
    match exception_type:
        case None: raise StopIteration()
        case _: raise exception_type(exception_message)
```

so I could do something like:

```py
gen = MyGenerator()
gen.throw(ValueError, "something went wrong")
```

to raise a `ValueError`.

To simplify things for SO purposes, on the C++ side I'm ignoring the fact that all arguments are optional. So, my first attempt was this member function implementation:

```cpp
void throw_(py::type exception_type, py::str exception_message, py::object /*traceback*/)
{
    throw exception_type(exception_message);
}
```

but when I run the code it actually throws a `RuntimeError`: "Caught an unknown exception!". Next thought was to cast the `ValueError` to `py::value_error`:

```
    throw py::cast<py::value_error>(exception_type(exception_message));
```

but it looks like the types are completely unrelated as I get `RuntimeError`: Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type.

So it looks like I need to manually check the type of the incoming python exception, then throw the equivlant pybind11 (or std) exception, which then gets retranslated to a python exception type on its way back to python. I could do something like this:

```cpp
void throw_(py::type e, py::str msg, py::object traceback)
{
    std::string type_str = py::cast<std::string>(py::str(e));

    if (e.is(py::none()))
        throw py::stop_iteration(msg);
    else if (type_str == "<class 'ValueError'>")
        throw py::value_error(msg);
    else if (type_str == "<class 'IndexError'>")
        throw py::index_error(msg);
    else if (type_str == "<class 'KeyError'>")
        throw py::key_error(msg);
    else if (type_str == "<class 'RuntimeError'>")
        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    throw e(msg);
}
```

but its really clunky, not least beacuse I have to know which exception types I deal with at compile time, but also using string comparisons to check types. Alternatively, I could exec python code in the function:

```cpp
void throw_(py::type e, py::str msg, py::object traceback)
{
    auto locals = py::dict("exception_type"_a=e, "exception_message"_a=msg);
    py::exec(R"""(
        raise exception_type(exception_message)
    )""", py::globals(), locals);
}
```

and this would solve the arbitrary exception type issue but again this seems a bit clunky because (I assume) the stack unwinds through pybind11, propagating the python exception type (is it caught and rethrown?), so it seems unnecessarily convoluted.

So really my questions are:

1. Is pybind11 really completely unaware of python exception types such as `ValueError`?
2. Is there a better way of checking the type than string comparison?
3. Is there another approach to this that is pure pybind11/C++?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want (not pure pybind11) but this

```
void throw_(py::object exception_type, const std::string& msg)
{
    PyErr_SetString(exception_type.ptr(), msg.c_str());
    throw py::error_already_set();
}
```

will throw an exception of the passed type.

Comment: thanks, that is definitely an improvement on execing python code.